# How to change MSYS2 Clang default search paths?

Tags: clang, msys2

I'm building now a library on Windows with MSYS2 Clang, and I have noticed that default search paths (ones you can find out by calling `clang --print-search-dirs`) are quite weird.

When I run this command from just `cmd.exe`, it gives me this:

```
programs: =C:/sdk/msys/clang64/bin
libraries: =C:/sdk/msys/clang64/lib/clang/16;C:/sdk/msys/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0;C:/sdk/msys/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib;C:/sdk/msys/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/mingw/lib;C:/sdk/msys/mingw64/lib
```

That is incorrect, all required libraries are installed to `C:/sdk/msys/clang64`.

However, when I run the same command from a builtin `clang64.exe` MinTTY shell, it gives me the correct result:

```
programs: =C:/SDK/msys/clang64/bin
libraries: =C:/SDK/msys/clang64/lib/clang/16;;C:/SDK/msys/clang64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib;C:/SDK/msys/clang64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/mingw/lib;C:/SDK/msys/clang64/lib
```

Both times it invokes the same `clang.exe` (I've doublechecked this), and I cannot find a thing in env that could affect this resolution.

What could possibly be done to get the correct search paths in `cmd.exe` environment?

**UPD:** Okay, just renaming `mingw64` folder did the trick, however, it does not seem to be a decent solution.

Comment: Do you perhaps have `mingw64\bin` in PATH? Remove it from there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes I do, but at the lowest priority (i.e. it comes last). Why in the name of Cthulhu is it programmed to take priority nevertheless?... I will give it a try though, thank you!

Comment: Clang on Windows has some weird logic to find which GCC installation it should connect to. Perhaps passing `--sysroot=C:\msys64\clang64` would convince it to ignore PATH.